# Flush responsive footer to bottom Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Well I know there are a million questions regarding this topic - but I haven't found an answer for my specific case.

I am wanting to create a sticky footer (not `position: fixed`) but one that will stay at the bottom if the content isn't sufficient to fill the page space. If there is enough content the footer will act as normal.

Well on other pages not using bootstrap I have been able to do this:

http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/

See it working on my site here:

http://www.magnetize.ca/policies.shtml#/pp

But on part of my site I am forced to use bootstrap and when I try the flexbox method things go really wrong:

http://my.magnetize.ca/knowledgebase.php

On most browsers I only see the footer get cut off on that page - but on Safari things get seriously messed up.

---

So, to summarize, I am looking for:

A sticky footer solution that:

- Isn't the fixed footer solution (acts as a normal footer if content is sufficient to fill page)
- Doesn't require a fixed footer height
- Works with bootstrap

Any help you could give me with this specific problem?

---

**EDIT:**

I am just trying out the "table trick" method as listed:
http://galengidman.com/2014/03/25/responsive-flexible-height-sticky-footers-in-css/

It is live now at: http://my.magnetize.ca/knowledgebase.php (on all my.magnetize.ca pages)

It is working much better than flex-box so I have ditched that idea. Everything is working beautifully on all browsers...except safari. On safari there are massive margins at the top and bottom of the page even though no margins are set.

Comment: What have you tried? SO isn't a place to ask for ideas. It's a place for you to ask for help with a specific problem you're having.

Comment: As I said - I've tried using the flex-box method, I am also just trying the "table trick" method http://galengidman.com/2014/03/25/responsive-flexible-height-sticky-footers-in-css/ right now. See "EDIT:"

Answer (score 0):

You could try using http://stickyjs.com/  I have used it for navigation bars that start in the middle of the page and then stick to the top.

I also found this http://www.cssreset.com/demos/layouts/how-to-keep-footer-at-bottom-of-page-with-css/# which looks more like what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this is what I want. As I said - I only want the footer to stick to the bottom when the page content isn't sufficient to fill the page.

Comment: Yes - the edit is more what I'm looking for but again that is only for non-responsive fixed height footers. I need it to work with variable height footers.